# hide secret key on django/pycharm mac

Tags: django, git, macos, pycharm

I'm making a simple CRUD app in django with the use of Pycharm.

I want to upload the project to Github and thus need to protect some of my settings.py file.

Would the best way to be use a .env file and add it to .gitignore or does that method not work on mac?

Comment: I'm confused. You want to hide the file from git? This is ok. But the title say about django and pycharm. So which key? Django probably need it, and it is handy to have a developer key in pycharm for testing. You may want to look up "deployment" guides to see how to deploy, but keeping secrets secret.

Answer (score -2):

Git has enable application "GitGuardian" please read about it. Or just prepare wrapper that will restore correct content of settings.py file, whenever you will start server.